# Can you use lightning-file-upload without saving?

Tags: lightning-web-components, fileupload

In LWC, is it possible to use the `lightning-file-upload` component without saving the file to a ContentDocument?

I am going to be uploading it to another server via an API and don't need/want it saved in Salesforce?

I know that it is possible to use a regular input and set `type="file"`, but I was wondering if this is the only option if you don't want it saved or if you could use existing functionality.

Answer (score 4):

There's a third option. You can use `lightning:input type="file"` option if you want the look and feel without saving the file to Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

So I was working off of an old example and didn't look at the documentation thoroughly.  Setting the type to file on a `lightning-input` seems to do everything I need.